# Time Complexity in Big O notation for 2 non nested different loop method

Tags: java, big-o

Since this 2 loops, iterate at different amount, whats can be the time complexity

```
int middleindex = items.length/2;
int index = 0;

while(index < middleindex){
     System.out.println(items[index]);
     index++;
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
     System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

Comment: Even for non-nested loops this is still `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

The first loop will take a time related to the number of items:

- if you have n items, it will take a time t.
- if you have 10 * n items, it will take 10 * t

So you can see that the computation time is **linearly** related to the number of items. It is O(n).

The second loop isn't related to the number of items, it will always run in **constant** time. It is O(1).

Comment: What if instead of 100 there was another variable X for a instance, which is not constant

Comment: Here, n is the size of your problem. If you introduce some variable, the resulting complexity of the second will depend on how it is related to n. For example, if it is linearly related to n ( 2n ,3n, etc...), the complexity will be linear. If it is quadratic (n * n), the complexity will be quadratic.